# Mobile Cognito signin

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito to signup/signin users from my iOS swift Mobile App. It seems that after login, a temporary token is provided. Until the token expires, the user does not need to signin when he relaunches it.
My use case is that I always want my users to sign in when they launch the app. Does anyone knows how to customise Cognito for this kind of behaviour ?
I do not want to force log out when the users kill the app, because there are several other cases for which I won't be able to log out (during crash for instance)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK can clear login state, perhaps you could store a timer for the last time they did sign in? Then when the app spins up, check that timer, and if it's above some threshold you could clear the login state and ask them to sign in again? That could handle a quick close and re-open.

Comment: Tks. I think that I can still ask for the users to enter their credentials and use the getSession function.